# Get table data from another website through wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, fetch

I was just wondering if it is possible to get the data from a table from another website through wordpress? And what would be the catch if I do that? And if it possible, How can I achieve it?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/pros-and-cons-of-adding-tables-to-the-wp-db?replies=8#post-1201613

You should have remote database access first

Comment: I actually dont have any access to the website. I just want to get the data from the table. And it was completely a different website.

Comment: Are you want just parse data from another website and this data is what you can see on this site?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's highly possible and I did it like this:

1. Create page template in Wordpress
2. Connect to remote database and check from backend first
3. Write UI code + server code + Mysql queries to grab the data in template
4. Create UI in page which will grab data from DB/server